# Implementation of ORB

Tags: feature-extraction, feature-detection, orb, feature-descriptor

I just used an open source implementation of an ORB.

How can I implement ORB further by adding new modules?

What can I do from my end in order to get better results than just using an ORB.

Am thinking of to use RANSAC for eliminating the outliers and to get better results.

Am struck at this point waiting for an ideas for further implementation of an ORB.

Any ideas on Homography implementation in circular and triangular shapes?